# Angular unit testing with parameter

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am writing a test for a method that takes in an id as a parameter to delete an object. The test case looks like below:

```
it('should delete the car object for the given ID', () => {
    const mockId = '1';
    const carObj = component.deleteCar(mockId);
    expect(carObj).not.toEqual('1');
  });
```

The test case passes. However when I change the value for assertion from '1' to '2', it still passes the test. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please share the code for the method: `deleteCar()`.

Answer (score 0):

It will always pass because your assertion is not correct.

I'm not entirely sure what your `deleteCar` returns. Looking at name, i think its a type of `Object` . So, assuming it is returning an object, you are asserting that the object is not '1' in your code block above. Which *will* pass, because '1' (string type) is indeed not equal to object `carObj`. Similarly, the case when you assert  `expect(carObj).not.toEqual('2');` will also pass, because 2 !== CarObject.

There is not much information, but I think you would ideally perform an action e.g. click of button, and this will trigger the function `deleteCar`, rather than you calling manually, like in the case bove